# How to remove a rendered template in MeteorJS?

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor

I have added a template rendering it dynamically:

```
var myTemplate = Meteor.render(Meteor.template.foo);
document.body.appendChild(myTemplate);
```

Now I want to remove this template from DOM, but this template have a list of elements.

The Meteor render, use a `documentFragment`, so I can't reuse the `myTemplate` variable because it doesn't have the content anymore.

What is the correct way to remove the template element contents from DOM using MeteorJS?

Comment: This will break the code. body may have more elements then my template one that I don't want to remove.

Comment: Something like that is what I'm doing right now, but doesn't looks like correct way, because Meteor bind the template elements with events, so if I just remove from DOM, the events will still existing and the GC will never remove that elements from the limbo. That's why I'm searching for the correct way to do it.

Comment: Rob, "template" means something more in Meteor than what you think about - it's not just a piece of DOM, it's an entire component with behavior, events and data. Removing one piece may cause the other ones to break.

Comment: @GabrielGartz: what are you trying to achieve? This is not the correct way to add a template to DOM in the first place, most of the time. You certainly don't want to do this in an event or callback, and in a helper you'd do this in a different way. Could you give a bigger picture?

Comment: @Rob, it doesn't change the way js FUNDAMENTALLY works with the dom, but it does things that cause FUNDAMENTAL methods to be wrong ones to use. An electric car works FUNDAMENTALLY in the same way a traditional one does - but you don't usually try to pump oil inside one.

Comment: I'm using jquery empty, because when it remove a child, it also remove it events. But the problem like @HubertOG said, I'm using a internall callback to add/remove the result from rendered template in the DOM, but looks like I'm doing something wrong, and if I do it write I will never need to care about removing the rendered template... That is what I understand after all this comments. So the answer probably is "there isn't, you need to use ??? resource display and remove templates from DOM"

Comment: Hi @GabrielGartz, cleaned up my end of the comments, hopefully leaving your q fresh for new ears . Hope you get sorted, Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the current rendering engine, I believe this will clean your injected template up satisfactorily if you've given the top level element in it the id `myTemplate`:

```
var thisNode = $('#myTemplate')[0];
Spark.finalize(thisNode);
$(thisNode).remove();
```

As you probably know, Spark is about to go away forever though, so this is only good for the time being.  I suspect that just `.remove`ing the element will be good enough in Blaze, but I can't really back that up with any evidence as I haven't made the switch yet...